# Random i character being printed into my string hash table despite appropriate datatypes

Tags: c, hashtable

Can anybody explain why my hash table program for strings is just printing the letter i in the first array instead of Ben? I do not specify i anywhere so am extremely puzzled as to why this result is showing:

I have correctly set my datatypes to char with the appropriate array lengths specified, so why is it that the string is not recognised?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define size 7

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *chain[size];

void init()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        chain[i] = NULL;
}

void add(char name[])
{
    //create a newnode with value
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = name[10];
    newNode->next = NULL;

    //calculate hash key
    char key = name[10] % size;

    //check if chain[key] is empty
    if(chain[key] == NULL)
        chain[key] = newNode;
    //collision
    else
    {
        //add the node at the end of chain[key].
        struct node *temp = chain[key];
        while(temp->next)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

/*
 * return 1, search found
 * return 0, Otherwise
 */
int search(int name)
{
    char key = name % size;
    struct node *temp = chain[key];
    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->data == name)
            return 1;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void print()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        struct node *temp = chain[i];
        printf("chain[%d]-->",i);
        while(temp)
        {
            printf("%c -->",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    //init array of list to NULL
    init();

    add("Ben");



    print();

    printf("Searching element 10\n");

    if(search(10))
        printf("Search Found\n");
    else
        printf("Search Not Found\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
chain[0]-->i -->NULL
chain[1]-->NULL
chain[2]-->NULL
chain[3]-->NULL
chain[4]-->NULL
chain[5]-->NULL
chain[6]-->NULL
Searching element 10
Search Not Found
```

Comment: Uh?   name[10] is out-of-bounds.

Comment: and: in `char data;`, *data* is a single character, not a *string*.

Comment: if i make char data into char data[10] i get error: array type 'char [10]' is not assignable
    newNode->data = name[10];

Comment: Also, I updated size to 10 and still get the same!!!

Comment: So now, there should be no reason for it to display this random i character

Comment: @wildplasser can you explain why that error occurs when i make data into data[10]

Comment: Because, in C,you cannot assign to an array. (in this case,you could use`strcpy()`)

Comment: "I have correctly set my datatypes to char " Looks like you haven't. I think you are confusing char, char *, int, strings.

Comment: "So now, there should be no reason for it to display this random i character" as @MartinJames said you are overflowing the array `name` so basically you are reading bullshit in memory. The ascii value for i is not worse than any other

Comment: When you call `add("Ben");` the `name` parameter (which is actually `char *name` because the compiler rewrites array parameters as pointers) points to a 4 `char` array initialized to `{'B', 'e', 'n', '\0'}`. So only elements up to `name[3]` are valid. But you are accessing `name[10]` which is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @IanAbbott how do i remedy this? If i remove the [10] from name, I get warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
      assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with *
      [-Wint-conversion]
    newNode->data = name;

Comment: You could access `name[0]`. That would give you the first letter. If you want more than that, you will need to change the `data` member into an array of suitable length, or a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. and copy the string using `strncpy` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically your code is good.

The error is, that you call `add()` like this:

```
add("Ben");
```

This means that the address of a 4 character array (exactly: the address of its first member) is given to `add()`. The 4 characters are:

1. 'B'
2. 'e'
3. 'n'
4. '\0'

Now in `add()` you read from the 11th character of the address given, at the offset of 10:

```
newNode->data = name[10];
```

This is called "out of bounds" and in Java (because you seem to know that) will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But C doesn't have such checks and so the code reads whatever is there. In your example it is an 'i' by accident.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. So are you suggesting that I do name[0] ?

Comment: It depends what you try to accomplish. `add()` can even be called with a `NULL` pointer. Your goal, your design, your choice. ;-)